# How to use scripting to remove fcurve for x and y location channels only?

Tags: python, animation, fcurves, actions

I want to remove the x and y locations in fcurve using codes.
I can remove all location channels in fcurve using codes, but I don't know which one x or y is.
If the fcurve contains x,y,z, I remove the first two. This is fine. What if the fcurve contains only x and z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... I somehow find the solution. Blender can figure out xyz channels by **array_index** of the location. 0->x,1->y,2->z. If I change 0 to 1, then I will get two Y-location channels...